how can i write unit test for react query and Next.js route handler
I fetch Hard-code data from the Next.js route handler with react query but my custom hook returns undefined.
my custom hook works fine in my component but in the test file returns undefined.
//route.ts

 export async function GET() {
  const data = [
    {
      title: "product one",
      price: 1200,
    },
    {
      title: "product two",
      price: 1200,
    }
 ];
 return Response.json(data);
}


//page.test.ts

test("isSuccess",  async () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useGetListingDataHook(), {
    wrapper: ReactQueryProvider,
  });
  await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.isSuccess).toBe(true));
 });

